# Bash script iterate over PID's and kill items

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, kill

I try to kill all occurrences of a process, what's happen actually an iteration stops after first item, what's wrong here ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SUPERVISORCLS=($(pidof supervisorctl))

for i in "${SUPERVISORCLS[@]}"
    do
        echo $i
        exec sudo kill -9 ${i}
    done
```

Before I tried sth like this as solution for restart script, but as well script was not always executed at total always only one if block was executed.?

```
ERROR0=$(sudo supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf  2>&1)

if [ "$ERROR0" ];then
    exec sudo pkill supervisord
    exec sudo supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
    echo restarted supervisord
fi

ERROR1=$(sudo supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf  2>&1)

if [ "$ERROR1" ];then
     exec sudo pkill -9 supervisorctl
     exec sudo supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
     echo restarted supervisorctl
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec` replaces your process with the executable that's the argument to it, so you will never execute another statement in your script after it hits an `exec`.  Your process will no longer exist.  In the first example your process will no longer be your script it will be `kill` and `pkill` in the second.

To fix it, just remove `exec` from all those lines.  It's not needed.  When executing a script the shell will execute the commands on every line already, you don't have to tell it to do so.